# Are there any symbolic math tools that can operate on matrices, without expanding the elements?

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I often want to know the general matrix answer to a problem such as (MATLAB notation):

```
diff(x'*M*x, x)
```

where x is a vector and M is a matrix. I only know how to do it by defining the matrix and vectors of a specified size, with each element a symbol, solving, and then trying to "put it back together" by eye to get the matrix version. Is this being done, or is it even feasible?

Comment: Do you have something like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2820966/339790) in mind?

Comment: Thanks for the lead.  I'll play with it and see if it does the kinds of operations I'm after.

Comment: Derivatives may be hard to deal with. Computing the directional derivative symbolically should be easy. The hard part is using, say, the cyclic property of the trace operator to extract a gradient from the directional derivative.